# Matplotlib legend, add items across columns instead of down

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

For a simple plot below, is there a way to make matplotlib populate the legend so that it fills the rows left to right, instead of first column then second column?

```
>>> from pylab import *
>>> x = arange(-2*pi, 2*pi, 0.1)
>>> plot(x, sin(x), label='Sine')
>>> plot(x, cos(x), label='Cosine')
>>> plot(x, arctan(x), label='Inverse tan')
>>> legend(loc=9,ncol=2)
>>> grid('on')
```

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I can think of one possible way. You can [order your legend items](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/legend_guide.html#adjusting-the-order-of-legend-items) as you like. All you need to do is to switch the order so that it will give you the result you want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import itertools

def flip(items, ncol):
    return itertools.chain(*[items[i::ncol] for i in range(ncol)])

x = np.arange(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), label='Sine')
ax.plot(x, np.cos(x), label='Cosine')
ax.plot(x, np.arctan(x), label='Inverse tan')

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(flip(handles, 2), flip(labels, 2), loc=9, ncol=2)

plt.grid('on')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, the legend will fill all allocated columns before adding a new row. You can therefore re-order the handles and labels together to take advantage of this:

```
handles, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = np.concatenate((handles[::2],handles[1::2]),axis=0)
labels = np.concatenate((labels[::2],labels[1::2]),axis=0)
```

Comment: I guess that this only works for 2 columns, with multiple columns one should use the accepted answer (and unfortunately add a function in the script to do this). I say unfortunately because it clutters the script for something that should be included in the matplotlib functions (in my opinion).