# Legend output order in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)
ax = plt.axes()
plot = []
plot += ax.plot(x, y1, label='sin(x)')
plot += ax.plot(x, y2, label='cos(x)')
plot += ax.plot(x, y1 * 2, label='sin(x)')
plot += ax.plot(x, y2 * 4, label='cos(x)')

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')

legend=['1', '2', '3', '4']
ax.legend(plot, legend, ncol=2)

plt.show()
```

How to change the order of legend output without changing arrays plot and legend?
The order should be as in the picture
[image]

Read the documentation. It is possible to do without handles?

Comment: Without handles - I'm afraid not; with handles - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101141/matplotlib-legend-add-items-across-columns-instead-of-down